# An Isomorphism of Rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be the ring of Quaternions over $\Bbb{Z}_{(3\Bbb{Z})}$ ($\Bbb{Z}$ localized in $3\Bbb{Z}$). Is it true that  $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ can be represented as  $M_2(\Bbb{Z}_3)$ ?
($\Bbb{Z}_3$ is the integers modulo 3).

Comment: [This was also posted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/137333/1916). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$Let us write, for every ring $R$,  $Q(R)$ for the quaternion algebra with coefficients in $R$.

The surjective map $f:\ZZ_{(3)}\to\ZZ/3$ induces a surjective map $F:Q(\ZZ_{(3)}\to Q(\ZZ/3)$. Since $\ZZ/3$ is a field, the ring $Q(\ZZ/3)$ is semisimple, and therefore the Jacobson radical $J(Q(\ZZ_{(3)})$ is contained in $\ker F$, which is the ideal generated by $3$ in $Q(\ZZ_{(3))}$. I claim that in fact $\ker F$ **is** the Jacobson radical.

To check this, it is enough to show that whenever $x$ is in $\ker F$ the element $1-x$ is invertible in $Q(\ZZ_{(3)})$, because this implies that $\ker F$ is contained in $J(Q(\ZZ_{(3)})$ (see, for example, I.M.Isaacs, *Algebra*, Theorem 13.4) Now if $x\in\ker F=3Q(\ZZ_{(3)})$, you can easily check that the norm of $1-x$, which is an element of $\ZZ_{(3)}$, is congruent to $1$ modulo $3\ZZ_{(3)}$ so it is in fact invertible in $\ZZ_{(3)}$: it follows from this that $1-x$ is invertible in $Q(\ZZ_{(3)})$.

So now we know that $Q(\ZZ_{(3)})/J(Q(\ZZ_{(3)}))$ is isomorphic to $Q(\ZZ/3)$. Now the quaternion algebra $Q(\ZZ/3)$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\ZZ/3)$, by the usual criterion for this to happen (it is given in this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra#Structure), for example)